# iOS 9 beta: Why are some promised features not in the beta? And: Time to update NDA!

Tags: discussion, ios

I know, I know... This probably looks like another idiot complaining that the *beta* of all things is buggy. I know right? *ZOMG WHATS THE POINT OF A BUGGY BETA??!?!?*

(╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻

(╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻

(╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻

But, I think this is a worthy question. And besides, I am pretty convinced it's not a bug. No, I am positive. I use an iPod Touch fifth generation, and am painfully aware of how ancient the processor is. I downloaded the iOS 9 public beta the other day, because after all, I had nothing to lose if the iPod 6 is coming tomorrow And it has gone surprisingly well! But I noticed that some of the features they advertise for iOS 9 are not there. Like the Smart Search thingy when you swipe right on the first page of the home screen. And also, I don't know if this is supposed to be a iPhone 6 only feature, but I am missing the Low Power Mode switch in settings.

I don't know if these features are supposed to be released later in a future beta release, if it's a problem with my A5 processor, or if I missed the memo on some information that would be fun to have at the moment. But I've held of from providing Apple with feedback yet, because I am pretty sure it's my fault somewhere or another... Anyway, if you are having a similar experience or have some blindingly obvious information that I overlooked, let me know. Thanks!

---

**Ok, hold the iPhone!**

Now, I understand why(maybe) my question has received down votes. Because I am discussing software that "hasn't been released to the public". However, I disagree. It is, in fact, and say it with me: a *public* beta. The key word there is *public*. In case you didn't notice the italic font I used there. Now,  technically, and this article proves it: [Are iOS 10, macOS 10.12, watchOS 3 or tvOS 10 (beta) questions OK?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1712/are-ios-9-and-os-x-el-capitan-questions-ok?cb=1)

Look at the excepted answer. What happens next will shock and amaze you.

> We do have precedent for allowing questions on software that is released in a beta status so if/when these OS versions get a wider release (perhaps as part of the OS X Beta seed program), we may have to revisit whether to
>   have the policy relaxed with respect to software that is pre-release.

That when, Ladies and gentlemen, is NOW. Like it or not.

Comment: ┬─┬ ┬─┬ ┬─┬ノ( º _ ºノ)

Comment: @Daniel Ok, great. There are like five answers. and a lot of them say different things. I say, NO. That site does _not_ have an answer. It has five different answers all saying different things, and no action was taken.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things

- welcome to Ask Different.
- Generally, discussion is OK on meta only - so if you post questions on the main site, don't ask for opinions or experience - narrow down the issue and just assume people with opinions or experience will answer.
- The community will need to have significantly more votes for the "yes" answer than the "no" answer in [Should beta OS questions be on-topic due to NDA changes + widening distribution by Apple](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2537/)
- Unless there is a groundswell of yes sentiment, then the status quo of "close them as they are off-topic" will continue (see [Are iOS 10, macOS 10.12, watchOS 3 or tvOS 10 (beta) questions OK?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1712/are-ios-9-and-os-x-el-capitan-questions-ok))

I personally answered the "yes" and "no" responses, so voting on them is out of my hands. Should I be a tie breaker, I'm likely to fall on "yes - let's try opening beta software for a trial" but ideally, the community will vote overwhelmingly for one answer to not need one moderator's tie breaker at all.

Comment: "Welcome to Ask Different" Ha! You seem to have me all figured out! Thanks for the info! I will look into the OS-On topic-NDA changes article.